# Input field value not recognizable when updated with DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bigcommerce

I am trying change input field values in big-commerce checkout page. When I try to change the value of the field using jquery, the value is successfully updated on the UI. But when I try to go to the next section, It says that the field is required.

[image]

So the problem is that, when I type something manually into the field, that's the only way the page allows me go to the next step, but If I change the value with DOM manipulation. It does not somehow recognize it.

Comment: We need the validation code to help

Comment: @PelegHaham Can you please explain a little bit about how can I get this validation code from the developer tools? I know we can inspect the attached event listeners on an element but I am unable to find relavent code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkout is a just an embedded React app. The checkout state is managed by React. Changing a value with JavaScript does not update the React state.

In order to update values in the checkout, you will need to use the storefront Checkouts API, and then trigger a page refresh. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/68accc5f14783-update-a-consignment

Comment: I have looked into the mentioned API & It requires consignment-id & checkout-id. Can you please tell me where can I obtain these?

Comment: You can make a get request to the checkout, passing in the includes parameter, to get these values. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/91f03b266ddb6-get-a-checkout